# Debian Image on Docker - How install Nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, curl, debian

I am writing a Dockerfile to run nodejs on a debian server but the compilation cannot be done. 
The dockerfile is like this :

```
FROM debian:9

RUN apt-get update -yq \
   && apt-get install curl gnupg -yq \
   && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash \
   && apt-get install nodejs -yq \
   && apt-get clean -y

ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 2368
VOLUME /app/logs

CMD npm run start
```

I execute the following instructions step by step

```
docker run --rm -it debian:latest

apt-get update

apt-get clean 

apt-get install curl gnupg -yq

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash
```

The last line tries to install the lsb-release package but an error occurs. The following lines appear :

```
+ apt-get install -y lsb-release > /dev/null 2>&1
Error executing command, exiting
```

I execute the command

```
apt-get install -y lsb-release
```

The last lines are

```
Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/python3-minimal_3.7.3-1_amd64.deb  Bad header line Bad header data [IP: 151.101.122.133 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3.7/python3.7_3.7.3-2+deb10u1_amd64.deb  Bad header line Bad header data [IP: 151.101.122.133 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have searched a long time but I do not know why this package wants to install and why it does not install.

Comment: Hello, 2latlantik is there any reason why do you do not use official docker images for node https://hub.docker.com/_/node/ there are some based on Debian, why do you do the extra job?

Comment: Hello. I try to follow a course offered by an online course site and it is a stage of the course. I start in docker and I'm not a linux expert.

Comment: Ou ok, keep up then mate :)

Comment: The end of the last command `... >/dev/null 2>&1` explicitly discards all output; if you remove those modifiers it should print out an actual error message.

Comment: I completed my question with the release of the command

Comment: can you try debian:9-slim

Comment: debian:9-slim doesn't work better ...

Answer (score 5):

I know this post is dated, but I recently ran into this problem and thought I would share the solution that worked for us.

We started with a Maven image based on Debian 11 / stable (Bullseye).

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends \
    open-ssl \
    curl \ 
    wget \
    git \
    gnupg \
    # more stuff

RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_current.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs \
    build-essential && \
    node --version && \ 
    npm --version
```

We successfully updated to node.js version 17.

Ultimately, this [github from nodesource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md) was the most helpful

Answer (score 0):

Could be because you have obsolete source PPAs.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
sudo apt-get update
```

and try installing.
Details [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141035/error-executing-command-exiting)

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work ... I had already seen this subject. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your Dockerfile works perfectly for me now with two different machines.
Maybe there was problem with server. IP is different now

```
curl -v http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/python3-minimal_3.7.3-1_amd64.deb -o test
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 151.101.246.133:80...
* Connected to deb.debian.org (151.101.246.133) port 80 (#0)
```

Comment: I actually wonder if it is not my VM that is bad. I have the basic configuration of the dockertoolbox

Answer (score 0):

hope this answer may help you. I actually accomplished making a nodejs CentOs image based on the actual nodejs docker image. If you enter to the next link, you may see how node docker image is constructed:

[node docker oficial image](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/910f8b1c0bdeee7bd464f0875297954bb86de9da/14/stretch/Dockerfile)

The first part of the node image runs commands to create a "node" user which I can't stress enough how good of a security practice is running your node containers from another user which is not "root". The second part comes the part I believe its going to help you; in all that code you have a part where you exchange gpg keys with a server and just after that, depending on your architecture, the nodejs program is downloaded from the nodejs oficial page and its prepared to be available to run. I think that your main problem is not importing the keys to the server, there in the image you should find the answer.

Also, in the image there comes a part responsible to detecting which architecture you have but mainly most architectures are going to be "x64". I include you me CentOs based node image (based on the oficial node image I linked you up) so you may look at it:

```
FROM centos:centos8

RUN groupadd --gid 1000 node \
    && useradd --uid 1000 --gid node --shell /bin/bash --create-home node

# node install taken from the node oficial image
ENV NODE_VERSION=12.16.3

RUN set -ex \
    && for key in \
       94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 \
       FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E \
       71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 \
       DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D \
       C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8 \
       B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9 \
       77984A986EBC2AA786BC0F66B01FBB92821C587A \
       8FCCA13FEF1D0C2E91008E09770F7A9A5AE15600 \
       4ED778F539E3634C779C87C6D7062848A1AB005C \
       A48C2BEE680E841632CD4E44F07496B3EB3C1762 \
       B9E2F5981AA6E0CD28160D9FF13993A75599653C \
     ; do \
       gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys "$key" || \
       gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" || \
       gpg --batch --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys "$key" ; \
     done \
     && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" \
     && curl -fsSLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
     && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
     && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - \
     && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 --no-same-owner \
     && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt \
     && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs \
     # smoke tests
     && node --version \
     && npm --version

CMD [ "node" ]
```

**OTHER INFORMATION**
Here I want to give you to other points that may help you in you Dockerfile but don't answer directly your answer (that's why I put it until the bottom):

1. I may believe you have your reasons, but the oficial nodejs docker image is actually based on debian (unless you choose alpine) so you may solve directly your problem by using `FROM nodejs:<version_you_want>`. I repeat, maybe you have a good reason to be doing it that way, but it doesn't hurt to give an advice :)
2. It is not consider good practice (I will put the link after this paragraph to the reference) to use "npm" to start a node image due to the following reasons

   1. The npm process starts a subprocess of node so you have to processes to run your application.
   2. The npm process have a known (not so known) problem called: "PID 1 Problem". As Bret Fisher, which is a docker captain and consultant states in the following article:

      > I recommend calling the node binary directly, largely due to the “PID 1 Problem”... Node.js accepts and forwards signals like SIGINT and SIGTERM from the OS, which is important for proper shutdown of your app. Node.js leaves it up to your app to decide how to handle those signals, which means if you don’t write code or use a module to handle them, your app won’t shut down gracefully. It’ll ignore those signals and then be killed by Docker or Kubernetes after a timeout period.

      It is better practice to run the "node" binary directly. As said in the article, npm doesn't handle SIGTERM/SIGINIT signals and node also doesn't handles them. The difference is that you may add code in node to handle those signals.

I include the node vs npm issue, it comes in the last part of the article and it also has many good nodejs docker practices :)

[keep nodejs rockin in decker](https://www.docker.com/blog/keep-nodejs-rockin-in-docker/)

Hope this could help you solve your doubts and helped you a little more to improve good practices. If you or anybody have any doubts, don't doubt to put it on the comments and I'll be happy to help if I can.

Have a nice day!